# Qt: connecting signal to slot having more arguments

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I want to connect a signal `clicked()` from the button to a slot of different object.

Currently I connect signal to helper method and call desired slot from there:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));

void buttonClicked() { // Helper method. I'd like to avoid it.
    someObject.desiredSlot(localFunc1(), localFunc2());
}
```

But maybe there is a more simple and obvious way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is this what you want to do:

the signal clicked should be connected to the "desiredSlot" which takes two arguments that are returned by localFunc1 & 2 ??

this is not possible, as you can read in the QT docs. A slot can take less arguments than provided by the signal - but not the opposite way! (The documentation says "This connection will report a runtime error")

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly. I wondered if there is any wrapper which can help me avoid creating such helper methods manually.

Answer (score 3):

This ought to work with the new signal/slot mechanism in qt 5:

```
connect( button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](){ someObject.desiredSlot( localFunc1(), localFunc2() ); } );
```

You will need to adjust the lambda capture to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, default arguments may help, e.g. declare desiredSlot as:

```
desiredSlot(int a=0, int b=0)
```

You cannot access members in default argument though.

Answer (score -1):

That is not the way to connect signals and slots in QT. You should use:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), receiver, SLOT(slotToBeCalled());
```

Have a look at the [QT documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: I've just skipped this in code sample. Now I've added it to post. @DeyyyFF understood me correctly.